# GitHub Actions run step only if file with specific ending changed

Tags: github, github-actions

So I made a github action which automatically gets the code from github, minify it using a minify-action and then push it to another branch. I now want to only run the minify **step** if a file ending with css js and html changed, because otherwise the minifier won't even do anything and building the docker image with node and stuff takes a lot of time.

So how can I run a specific **step** only if files with a specific **ending** changed? I don't have another job, I can make one, but the step is inbetween two other steps.

Comment: You can create a step to check that and [set up an output variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#using-workflow-commands-to-access-toolkit-functions). Then, in your next step, you can use that variable in your if condition, eg: `if: ${{ success() && steps.verify-files.outputs.should-run }}`

Comment: you mean like [this](https://gist.github.com/SIMULATAN/ccfda195d830092ff352829402611743)?

Comment: if yes, I don't know how to resume with the other steps after the checks because the minify action itself is in the middle of two other steps

Answer (score 0):

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    paths:
      - '*.py'
```

When you use paths, your action won't execute until the file you specified on paths has been modified.